# Bubble sort in c linked list

Tags: c, sorting, struct, linked-list, bubble-sort

I need to do is read in an input file into a linked list. Part of the file is:

NameA, 25
NameB, 33
NameC, 23
NameD, 39

And after i need to sort by the number (bubble sort) and write it to another file.

Here is what i have:

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node{
    char name[20];
    int number;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
}*head;

int main(void) {

    struct node *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;

    FILE *ifp;
    char fnamer[100] = "";
    char line[128];
//    printf("\n\nPlease Enter the Full Path of the file: \n");
//    scanf("%s",&fnamer);

    ifp = fopen("mintaadatok.txt", "r");
    if (ifp == NULL) {
        printf("\n%s\" File NOT FOUND!", fnamer);
        exit(1);
    }

    int c = 0;

    char buffer[1024];
    memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
    while (c < 15) {
        fgets(buffer, 1024, ifp);
        sscanf(buffer, "%19[^,], %d", temp->name, &temp->number);
        printf("%d %s %d\n", c, temp->name, temp->number);
        temp->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = NULL;
        c++;
    }

    int i,step;
    for (temp = head; temp; temp = temp->next) {
        printf("%s", temp->name);
        printf("%d\n", temp->number);
        for(step=0;step<10-1;++step)
            for(i=0;i<10-step-1;++i)
            {
                temp->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                if(temp->number>temp->next)
                {
                    temp=temp->number;
                    temp->number=temp->next;
                    temp->next=temp;
                }
            }
    }
    printf("In ascending order: ");
}
```

Can you help me to sort these data?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @AditiRawat I couldnt bubble sort the linked list

Comment: @coderredoc yes it would help a lot

Comment: Firstly you have not written any code for the sort method; you are just populating the list. Secondly in order to perform almost any operations on linked lists you require a `head` pointer which you have not stored here. And lastly if you have the `head` pointer, a simple google search (your question title) would yield useful results.

Comment: We can only help you for logic. You have to write your own code, at lease you have to try.  to try, You need a link list.! Your list code should work as i analyzed. I suppose you need to sort the data with `id`. You need to check every two link list element same as the bubble sort to sort. In this case you will traverse through link list. Try out, Tell if it doesn't work. You should not expect other user's to write code for you. we will help you if you try first.

Comment: @AditiRawat Thank you for the information, and as you see i do not understand the c yet. I try write the sorting, but it didnt woked, i could do with a simple array but not this. Thats why i asked to help.

Comment: Then you should probably show us the sorting code you have written and we might then be able to help. :)

Comment: @AditiRawat Updating my code. I know this is bad now, but i dont get the idea. Im a little bit desperate.

Comment: @AditiRawat He defined the header node struct node{
    char name[20];
    int number;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
}*head;
 and I very doubt that a google search will help to find a good bubble sort function for a singly linked list compared with the function I showed in my answer.:)

Comment: @khlan - I'm wondering if this assignment is to be implemented by changing the next and prev pointers rather than swap the contents of the nodes as was done in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We beginners should help each other.:)

I did not look through all your code. However it is obviously incorrect for example due to the incorrect order of allocations of nodes in this loop

```
while (c < 15) {
    fgets(buffer, 1024, ifp);
    sscanf(buffer, "%19[^,], %d", temp->name, &temp->number);
    printf("%d %s %d\n", c, temp->name, temp->number);
    temp->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp = temp->next;
    temp->next = NULL;
    c++;
}
```

So the last node will have data members with indeterminate values except the data member `next`.

I am trying to answer your question **how to write a bubble sort function for a singly-linked list**.

To write a bubble sort function for a singly-linked list is not an easy task for such beginners as you and me. For example you need to write correctly a swap function for nodes of the list.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    char name[20];
    int id;
    struct node *next;
};

int push_back( struct node **head, const char *name, int id )
{
    struct node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        strcpy( tmp->name, name );
        tmp->id = id;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        *head = tmp;
    }

    return success;
}

void display( struct node **head )
{
    for ( struct node *current = *head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "{ %s, %d } ", current->name, current->id );
    }
}

void swap( struct node **current )
{
    struct node *tmp = ( *current )->next->next;
    ( *current )->next->next = *current;
    *current = ( *current )->next;
    ( *current )->next->next = tmp;
}


void bubble_sort( struct node **head, int cmp( const void *, const void * ) )
{
    if ( *head != NULL )
    {
        for ( struct node *last = NULL, *swapped = NULL; ( *head )->next != last; last = swapped )
        {
            swapped = ( *head )->next;

            for ( struct node **first = head; ( *first )->next != last; first = &( *first )->next )
            {
                if ( cmp( ( *first )->next, *first ) < 0 )
                {
                    swap( first );
                    swapped = ( *first )->next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int cmp_id( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const struct node *left  = a;
    const struct node *right = b;

    return ( right->id < left->id ) - ( left->id < right->id );
}

int cmp_name( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const struct node *left  = a;
    const struct node *right = b;

    return strcmp( left->name, right->name );
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct node *head = NULL;

    push_back( &head, "NameA", 25 );
    push_back( &head, "NameB", 33 );
    push_back( &head, "NameC", 23 );
    push_back( &head, "NameD", 39 );    

    display( &head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    bubble_sort( &head, cmp_id );

    display( &head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    bubble_sort( &head, cmp_name );

    display( &head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
{ NameA, 25 } { NameB, 33 } { NameC, 23 } { NameD, 39 } 
{ NameC, 23 } { NameA, 25 } { NameB, 33 } { NameD, 39 } 
{ NameA, 25 } { NameB, 33 } { NameC, 23 } { NameD, 39 }
```

In the demonstrative program at first the list is sorted by IDs and then by names.

Thus all you need now is to build correctly the list from data in the used file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks good :)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow. You forgot to `free()`  ==>>> `total heap usage: 5 allocs, 1 frees, 1,152 bytes allocated`

Comment: @Michi I did not forget. It is a demonstrative program that includes only those functions that are required to provide sorting.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I agree, but informing the OP about `free` would be not bad :).

Comment: @Michi It is his task to write correctly all functions for a singly-linked list/ My task was to show how such a list can be sorted using the bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

for bubble sorting a linked list,you first require a head pointer then two more pointers and the implementation will be same as that of bubble sort but with slight differences as linked list element can not be accessed by directly by a index you have to use the following two pointers for comparing values as you do for arrays in bubble sort.

```
    pptr=head;  //for the previou element
    ptr=head->next;//for the next element

   if(pptr->value > ptr->value)  //comparing the value in linked list
```

don't forget to increment two pointers.