# Swap nodes in a linked list without swapping data

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort

how can i use pointers without copying the data?
I want to write a bubble sorting function, but I got stuck, and need some help how to swap node addresses instead of values. 
I have a file with city names, and temperatures:

- Las Vegas, 25
- New York, 33
- Chicago, 23
- Houston, 39

and I need to sort it by the temperature, and write it to another file.

UPDATE:
Ok, now I think i understand the theoratical part:

```
// p is my node
// p-prev -> p -> p-next -> p-next-next
prev->next = p->next;
p->next = p->next->next;
prev->next->next = p;
```

This is what i need to do, to swap the nodes, but syntactically i couldnt make it work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char name[128];
    int id;
    struct node *next;
}*head;

void readFile() {
    char fnamer[128] = "";
    printf("\nEnter the file name to read (delimiter: ,): \n");
    scanf("%s",&fnamer);
    FILE *inf = fopen(fnamer, "r");

    char buffer[1024];
    memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
    while(fgets(buffer, 1024, inf)){
        struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->next = NULL;

        if(sscanf(buffer, "%19[^,], %d", temp->name, &temp->id) != 2){
            free(temp);
            break;
        }

        if(!head){
            head = temp;
        } else{
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        }
    }

    fclose(inf);
}

int main(void) {
    // Read a linked list from file
    readFile();

    //Bubble sort in linked list
    struct node *loop1 = head;
    while(loop1){
        struct node *loop2 = loop1->next;
        while(loop2){
            if(loop1->id > loop2->id){

                // Swap next pointers
                // This is not working
                struct node *temp = loop1->next;
                loop1->next = loop2->next;
                loop2->next  = temp;

            }
            loop2 = loop2->next;
        }
        loop1 = loop1->next;
    }

    // Print the sorted linked list to file:
    char foutname[100]="";
    printf("\nPlease Enter the file name to write the result: \n");
    scanf("%s",&foutname);

    FILE *outf;
    outf = fopen(foutname, "w+");

    loop1 = head;
    while(loop1){
        printf("%s %d\n", loop1->name, loop1->id);
        fprintf(outf, "%s %d\n", loop1->name, loop1->id);
        loop1 = loop1->next;
    }
    fclose(outf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to keep track of the previous nodes to `loop1` and `loop2`, and swap the next pointers of those in addition to the next pointers of `loop1` and `loop2`.  You also need to account for the case that `loop1->next` is the same as `loop2`.

Comment: `... }*head;` Note: head is uninitialised.

Comment: @wildplasser It is initialized as a variable with the static storage duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to swap the `next` links such that the link chain is rearranged. If you swap `node1` and `node2`, the link chain should change as follows:

```
//change the link chain from
node0 -> node1 -> node2 -> node3
//to
node0 -> node2 -> node1 -> node3
```

We put this inside a `while` loop and the loop breaks when there are no more swaps. We can improve this function by limiting the number comparisons. After each loop, the last element should be sorted.

To put this together,lets use `typedef` keyword so that we don't have to repeat `struct` everywhere.

```
typedef struct node_t
{
    char name[20];
    int id;
    struct node_t *next;
} node;

void bubblesort(node **list)
{
    if(!(*list)) return;
    node *previous_node = NULL;
    node *sort_up_to = NULL;
    while(1)
    {
        previous_node = NULL;
        node *ptr = *list;
        node *last_change = NULL;
        while(ptr->next)
        {
            //the rest of the list is sorted?
            if(sort_up_to && ptr == sort_up_to) break;

            node *next = ptr->next;
            if(ptr->id > next->id)
            {
                if(previous_node == NULL)
                    *list = next;
                else
                    previous_node->next = next;
                ptr->next = next->next;
                next->next = ptr;
                last_change = next;
            }

            previous_node = ptr;
            ptr = next;
        }

        //list is all sorted?
        if(!last_change) break;

        sort_up_to = last_change;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    node* head = NULL;

    FILE *fin = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if(!fin)
        return 0;

    node temp;
    while(fscanf(fin, "%19[^,], %d\n", temp.name, &temp.id) == 2)
    {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        n->next = NULL;
        strcpy(n->name, temp.name);
        n->id = temp.id;
        if(head)
            n->next = head;
        head = n;
    }
    fclose(fin);

    bubblesort(&head);

    for(node* n = head; n != NULL; n = n->next)
        printf("%s %d\n", n->name, n->id);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer its always helpful, and gives a deeper understanding :)

Answer (score 3):

To swap two nodes in a singly-linked list you can use the following function

```
void swap(struct node **current)
{
    struct node *tmp = (*current)->next->next;
    (*current)->next->next = *current;
    *current = (*current)->next;
    (*current)->next->next = tmp;
}
```

For example to swap the head node and the next node you can call the function like

```
swap( &head );
```

See also my answer at this reference [Bubble sort in c linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639448/bubble-sort-in-c-linked-list/47640875#47640875) where there is shown how to write the bubble sort algorithm for a singly-linked list.

Comment: Thanks for sharing singly-linked list bubblesort function  it was helpful and finally i got it :)